# There is no error when str is passed in when the field type is int?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am verifying the data in the dictionary. I specify that the age field is of type int, but in practice, the age I pass in is of type str. Why is there no error?

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()


user_data = {
    "name": "Ken",
    "age": "12"
}

try:
    UserSchema().load(user_data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, marshmallow casts `"12"` into an `int`.

If you want to ensure it is an `int` and not a string, use the `strict` parameter.

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Integer

> strict – If True, only integer types are valid. Otherwise, any value castable to int is valid.

```py
class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int(strict=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that *marshmallow.fields* is parsing age into an int implicitly at some point and it's throwing no exceptions because "12" converts nicely into 12. When I run your code this is exactly what happens, `name` is "Ken" and `age` is 12. If I change "12" to "12a" though, then it returns an exception as you would expect.